# IIS Missing Response header over different Networks

Tags: iis, cross-domain, response, webrequest, iis-10

I have an IIS10 Webserver and multiple sites on it.

Now I have experienced something quite odd. If I connect to the website via the internet (external network) everything seems fine and all configured Response Headers (Tried both setting them in web.config and in the IIS Feature "HTTP Response Headers) are returned. But when I access the same URL via an Computer on the same network, then most of the configured headers are missing.

Here are the settings on the IIS Server

[IIS Server Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXz8m.png)

Here is the response I get over the internet (Access-Control Headers are added over ASP.NET global.asax):

[Response Headers Remote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVdJF.png)

and here's the Response Headers when accessing the same URL over a machine in the same network:

[Response Headers Same Network Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOmdX.png)

as you can see, the Header "Body-Count" is not present on the machine in the same network. But the X-Powered-By is. If I remove the X-Powered-By Header, then it is not present on both machines. I know that the X-Powered-By Header is configured on the Root of the IIS Server, but if I add any other Response Headers there I get an 500 Internal Server error on all of my requests as a response...

Comment: It is a strange behavior that some headers missing. What's the network environment of second machine? Does IIS and second machine in same network or second machine and first machine in same network? What about setting custom headers at server level, will headers still miss? If so, please use failed request tracing to troubleshoot what headers happened?

Comment: So the enviroment is, that I have my companies network where we have an IIS and several workstatons. These are in the same network and this is where the request headers are missing (I enter the URL webpage normally in chrome). When I access the URL over my computer at home or over a VPN (tried through germany) the headers are present. I will give the failed request tracing a try and report back!